# getcases for specified testruns in a testplan

Tags: testrail

I have 1 testplan RC_3.0 in a testrail
In that, I have several testruns(TR1, TR2...TRn) which contain many testcases and its results.
The goal is to get all the testcases from these testruns for the testplan RC_3.0.
Objective is to know all the testcases executed for this RC_3.0.
I am trying to get information from this api:

> get_cases

> Returns a list of test cases for a project or specific test suite (if the project has multiple suites enabled).

```
GET index.php?/api/v2/get_cases/{project_id}&suite_id={suite_id}
```

Is it possible to just give the testplan (RC_3.0) and retrieve all the runs and testcases attached to it via api? Or how can I retrieve all testcases and its results for a particular Testplan?
`GET index.php?/api/v2/get_cases/{Project_Id}&suite_id=XXX&milestone_id=YYY"))`
: this gives me >1000 testcases ..but I just want for a particular Testplan and not for a complete milestone.
Is that possible via an api?

Regards,